# How to adjust buffer length for https to receive data (event 'data') when test with Jasmine on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have the following code to make a GET request in https (only code section that matters)

```
const lib = require('https');
var dataChunks = [];
const request = lib.get(url, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        // get chunk of data here ...
        dataChunks.push(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
        // combine all chunk of data
        var fullData = dataChunks.join('');
        // do something further ...
    });
});
```

I then tested it both on `browser` and `NodeJS` to request for a somewhat large enough data that it needs to send multiple of `'data'` events back.

Here is what I found for making a request to the same large data

1. In case of testing on `browser`, I did receive multiple of events.
2. In case of testing on `NodeJS`, I did receive only once.

I guess it's because as testing on NodeJS, you use the system's pre-defined setting or some sort not to limit by browser. So it might be able to sum up in only one event. For certain reason, I want to write a test code via karma-jasmine that requires such event to be fired multiple times similar to what happened on `browser`.

The question is how could I adjust or configure things running code on NodeJS to have the same result on browser in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad, I add detail here for someone else that would be facing the similar issue.

Even running test via karma-jasmine, you configure which browser to test against. The reason for testing that gives different result is because I tested on `browser` via Chrome, and tested on `NodeJS` against `Firefox` as set in karma-jasmine.

This seems to let us know that there's higher buffer length in Firefox compared to Chrome. Now I changed back and I got the same result now.

Finally this would mean that buffer length depends on setting on each browser.